# Remove underline from hyperlink - Rails

Tags: html, css

I've been looking and looking and I can't seem to change this really annoying thing!!!!
So please people you gently angels, help me remove underline from my links, but specific ones.
The severely messed up ones, thanks.

Some code:

```
    <div id = "cracker-container">

      <div class = "cracker-wrapper">
      <div id = "cracker1-button">
        <%= link_to "cracker", new_crack_path %>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class = "cracker-wrapper">
    <div id = "cracker2-button">
        Cracker2
    </div>
     </div>

    <div class = "cracker-wrapper">
     <div id = "cracker3-button">
      Cracker3
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

THE CSS:

#cracker1{
  color: #000;
}

#cracker2{
  color: #000;
}

#cracker3{
  color: #000;
}

#cracker1:active{
  color: #fff;
}

#cracker2:active{
  color: #fff;
}

#cracker3:active{
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We try to keep things polite around here, so please refrain from using profanities in your questions in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I see I respect that. Though I wasn't impolite towards anybody, only my code. Swearing gave more emotions to my code. You know ;)

Comment: I get that way too, from time to time :) Just be careful not to include that kind of thing in your questions - you may end up [warned, suspended or even banned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/157398).

Comment: **** hehe f*** *u** **c* ***k No problem ;) Not a chance I'll get banned :P And by the way, I'll stop now. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will remove the text-decoration from any  tags under the #cracker1-button div.

```
#cracker1-button a:link { 
    text-decoration:none; 
}
```

However, that code will only remove the underlines from "fresh"/un-visited links. A link has 4 different states:

- *link*: Fresh/un-visited links
- *visited*: Links the user has visited
- *hover*: When the user is hover over the link with the mouse
- *active*: When the link is the active element on the page (has keyboard focus)

If you want to remove underlining from the link in all 4 states, you will need to specify it in your CSS:

```
#cracker1-button a:link, #cracker1-button a:visited, #cracker1-button a:hover, #cracker1-button a:active,  { 
    text-decoration:none; 
}
```

Here is a reference for more information on styling links with CSS.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 0):

`#cracker1-button a { text-decoration:none; }`

No idea if that's what you're after, but that will remove the underline from links in `#cracker1`.

Comment: I'm only after removing that as*fu***d da**ed underline. Since the #cracker1 is changing color and such, though this is the simplified version and it shows up like two cracker buttons beside one another. is the solution that simple really? :S Either you're a genius or I'm a dumn****ed ass**du**mne*. But I haven't used any "a" tags, so how can you use #cracker1 a { text-decoration: none } then??

Comment: I'm assuming that `<% link_to %>` business will generate a anchor element. Is that not right?

Comment: Exactly! /m/ /m/ **EDIT** that means that if will exist even if I don't type it in? RIght? Am I right?